# Supervisor not reloading Gunicorn properly with Django project

Tags: linux, ubuntu, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am using **Supervisor** to reload **Gunicorn** when pushing **Django** project to production :

**Workflow** :

```
          " && python manage.py migrate"\
          " && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"\
          " && supervisorctl restart frontdesk-gunicorn"\
          " && exit"
```

**Supervisor config** :

```
   [program:project-gunicorn]
    command=/home/gaetangr/project/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application
    user = gaetangr
    directory = /home/gaetangr/project
    autostart = true
    autorestart = true
```

But most of the time, in order for all the change to propagate, I have to do a sudo :

`systemctl restart gunicorn`

From my understanding the command from supervisor should exactly the same.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`superviserd` manages processes by creating subprocesses. If you start `gunicorn` with `systemctl` then `superviserd` won't know anything about this  `gunicorn` and won't be able to restart it.  Use only one process managment system - either `supervisord` or `systemd`.

Comment: Thanks, so the solution is to stop my service with Gunicorn and only use supervisor ? 
It is true that I use Gunicorn for one year and only recenlty start using supervisor.